# How to show if n is prime, then $\{1,2,.....,n-1\}$ is a group?

Tags: abstract-algebra

The set $\{1, 2, 3, ..., n - 1\}$ is group under multiplication modulo $n$ if and only if $n$ is a prime number.

I have showed that if ${1,2,...,n-1}$ is group, then n must be prime, but don't have any idea how to prove converse part. Any simple solution ?

Comment: Do you know Bezout's identity?

Answer (score 0):

**HINT** There are only finitely many elements and there are no zero divisors (since $n$ is prime). Then choose a non-zero element $a$ in the set, and consider all products $aa_1$. Since the set is finite, multiplication must be bijective...

Answer (score 0):

When $n:=p$ is prime then for any two elements $a$, $b$ in your set $S$ the product $ab$ is not divisible by $p$, and therefore has a representative in $S$. In order to show the existence of inverses choose any $a\in S$ and consider the map $$M_a: \quad S\to S,\qquad x\mapsto a\,x\quad {\rm mod}\>p\ .$$
When $M_a(x)= M_a(y)$  then $a(x-y)$ is divisible by $p$, which implies $x=y$. It follows that $M_a$ is injective, and as $S$ is finite $M_a$  is then also surjective. It follows that there is an $a'\in S$ with $a\, a'=1$.

Answer (score 0):

If n is prime then no element of given set will be factor of n. For any two elements a and b of the set, (ab)mod(n) will be in the set. This implies the set holds closure law.
Associativity is obvious and 1 will be identity of the set under given operation.
For any element a of the set choose a' such that aa'-1=qn where q is any integer. Since,n is a prime so,for exactly one q, a' belong to the given set. Here (aa')mod(n) will be 1. So, a' is inverse of a.
Hence the set holds all properties of being a group.